# Cómo insertar un dato en la tabla sin tener que especificar todos los campos

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero insertar un dato en una columna especifica y no tener que seleccionar todas las columnas, vemos *camp1, camp2, camp3...* Donde solo lo voy a insertar en el *camp3*

¿Qué puedo hacer?

```js
$data_table = mysqli_query($file,"INSERT INTO $table (camp1,camp2,camp3,...) VALUES ('$data','','')");
```

Comment: Saludos. Como tal; con indicar (en tu caso) luego de **$table** entre paréntesis la columna(s) y en **VALUES** igual numero de datos y del mismo tipo bastara; solo que las demás columnas que no especifiques deberán tener asignado un valor por default o permitir **NULL** (que seria su valor por default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Existen varias opciones para poder insertar nuevo valor

Tu código actual tiene cada columna declarada con un correspondiente valor:

```
$data_table = mysqli_query($file,"INSERT INTO $table (camp1,camp2,camp3) VALUES ('$d1','$d2','$d3')");
```

Pero para insertar valores existen mas variantes:

**Opción 1**: Insertar solo **valores sin detallar columnas**, los valores van en orden de columnas:

```
//Solo valores sin columnas
$data_table = mysqli_query($file,"INSERT INTO $table VALUES ('$d1','$d2','$d3')");
```

**Opción 2**: Insertar valores solo en algunas columnas, pero en este caso es necesario que **detalles** cuales serán las **columnas** que utilizaras para asignarle los valores:

```
// Solo camp1 y camp3
$data_table = mysqli_query($file,"INSERT INTO $table (camp1,camp3) VALUES ('$d1','$d3')");
```

o también una solo columnas:

```
// Solo camp2
$data_table = mysqli_query($file,"INSERT INTO $table (camp2) VALUES ('$d2')");
```

Espero que sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Suponiendo que los demás campos "permiten" nulos y que tu sentencia original es correcta, debería quedar algo así:

```
$data_table = mysqli_query($file,"INSERT INTO $table (Camp1) VALUES ('$data')");
```

(Igual debes indicar el campo del valor que vas a insertar).

Comment: Supongo que querías decir: *que los demás campos __permiten__ nulos*